# Sharing data between HttpSession and FlexSession

Tags: apache-flex, jsp, session, rtmp, lcds

I know it sounds silly but that s the situation we are in:

1. In index.jsp, wehave to capture Http Header containing the username of working user sent from browser (it is kinda single sign on of our organization)
2. In RemoteObject and Assembler (LCDS, ADEP) , we need to retrieve the username for data processing.

So far, we put username in HttpSession in #1, then in #2 we retrieve it. Lucky, it works because RemoteObject runs over amf (which is http). We find it not very portable because if RemoteObject is switched to rtmp, it won't work.

Please advise us.

Answer (score 0):

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_pass_on_dynamic_data_from_a_JSP_wrapper_to-8410.html

I think this one fits our situation best